# Spacing between the different environments

Tags: spacing, environments

I want to separate more clearly the different theorems, definitions, examples, ... So I need the space between these different environments to be bigger than space between paragraphs. Is there a global command to insert before the "\begin{document}" ?

Comment: The space between paragraphs is usually zero.

Comment: It depends on you document class and package.  You can try increasing \topsep and/or \partopsep.  I only see \parskip being used by \endtrivlist.

Comment: You might consider throwing in the occasional \hrule.